# Can we change the Projected columns based on a specific value in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I was wondering of we can change the Projected columns based on a specific value in Kusto.

Example: in below datatable, we need to project only **Name** if **IsActive** is **1**, else project both **Name** and **Company**.

```html
let sampleTable = datatable(Name:string, Company:string, IsActive:bool, Location:string)
[   
    "ABC","Microsoft",1, "Redmond",
    "XYZ","Amazon",1, "Seattle",
    "EFG","Google",0, "Mountain View",
    "MNO","Facebook",0, "Menlo Park",
    "QRS","Apple",0, "Cupertino"
];
sampleTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Projecting columns based on conditions on rows data might not be possible in KQL. As per your data, the below kind of projectio is possible.

```
let sampleTable = datatable(Name:string, Company:string, IsActive:bool, Location:string)
[
"ABC","Microsoft",1, "Redmond",
"XYZ","Amazon",1, "Seattle",
"EFG","Google",0, "Mountain View",
"MNO","Facebook",0, "Menlo Park",
"QRS","Apple",0, "Cupertino"
];
sampleTable
| project Name,Company=iif(IsActive==1,"",Company);
```

Here it will project both columns but as per the rows condition, it will give empty string for `Company` when `IsActive==1`.

[image]